# Python: Call function on each/any file in a module (dynamically)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to make a library of files, where each file does basically the same - solving math problems - but each implementation is slightly different. The way I want to set this up is as follows:

```
main.py          (has a list of all problems, user can enter parameters)
solves\
    prob001.py   Problem, with definition of inputs, perhaps several different 
                 solve() methods(solve_1(), solve_2() ...)
    prob002.py   2nd Problem, structurally the same.
    ....
```

As I progress, more `problemXX.py`'s  will be added.

What code would I need to call `solve_1` on `prob002.py`, and how do I make this as flexible/scalable as possible. Simply typing out `import prob001` then `prob001.solve(x, y)` is not preferred, I want to generate menu's with options dynamically.

Comment: I think I understand where you are going with this, but to be sure: Eventually there will be a menu interface where you can combine different solving methods (by contradiction, by induction, etc.) on the different problems (prob001, prob002, etc.)?

Comment: @thenarfer No, not quite. Each problem will have its own set of Solve-methods which might vary in approach, performance, etc. I'm not planning on generalising that.
I'm mostly unsure of how to dynamically generate the menu button to run Problem 1, Solver 2 with params set to X and Y.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. So this is a question about generating an interface and connecting it with the structure of scripts and their functions?

Comment: @thenarfer Yeah, I guess that's how you could look at it.

Answer (score 1):

Files: https://gist.github.com/thenarfer/330a4f978eab7c40e84e1dbaee062ebd

Check out the files for this script. Make sure to create the directory tree as follows:

```
math_solver_main.py          
solves\
    prob001.py   
    prob002.py
    ...
```

[image]

[image]

You can add more problems and the script will recognize it. I'm quite sure that this is not exactly what you are looking for, but possibly you can edit the contents of the problems and the execution of math_solver_main.py to your needs.